# Java: Easiest way to compare two xmls

Tags: java, xml

I have two xmls:

```
first.xml

<text>This is text</text>
<output>This is output</output>

second.xml

<text>This is not text</text>
<output>This is output</output>
```

I want to compare these two xmls and output should like this

```
<text>This is <inserted>not</inserted> text</text>
    <output>This is output</output>
```

Means, I want to add a new tag suppose `<inserted>` to newly added text.
How to compare these xmls and create new one ?

Thanks for ur time :)

Comment: I would not consider this a duplicate since the original question was 3 1/2 years ago, and the solution ([XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)) hasn't had a release in over 2 years.  Also, I would not consider using a unit testing library to solve a programming problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Nice to use in Unit tests, very good output.

Comment: Why do you think this question is about testing?  This is just the answer of the alleged duplicate, and is a library that hasn't had a release in over 2 years.

Comment: Because I thought that comparing if two XML files are the same quite like as making a test if two XML files are the same

Comment: @Farmor - the body of the question makes it clear that the OP wants the differences between the XML documents ... not just a yes/no answer.